# SharePoint 2013 custom TimerJob gets no results from list but same code as a console program returns results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, client-object-model, caml-query, timer-jobs, custom-timer-job

Can anyone provide any ideas on why the below query returns nothing when inside a custom timer job. But when run from a console program it returns results.  Note, both console program and OWSTimer.exe are running as the same user "Administrator".

```
SPContentDatabase contentDb = webApp.ContentDatabases[contentDbId];
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
IList<Engagement> items = new List<Engagement>();
SPFieldLookupValue valSection;

query.ViewFields = @"<FieldRef Name=""FileRef"" /><FieldRef Name=""Section"" />";
query.Query = "<Where><And>" +
        "<Gt><FieldRef Name=\"Modified\" /><Value IncludeTimeValue=\"TRUE\" Type=\"DateTime\">2012-08-22T09:15:15Z</Value></Gt>" +
        "<IsNotNull><FieldRef Name=\"Section\" /></IsNotNull></And></Where>";

query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;

try
{
    SPList list = contentDb.Sites[0].RootWeb.Lists["IOF"];

    foreach (SPItem item in list.GetItems(query))
    {
    valSection = new SPFieldLookupValue(item["Section"].ToString());
    items.Add(new Engagement(valSection.LookupValue, item["FileRef"].ToString().Replace(@"/IOF/", ""), path + item["FileRef"].ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're opening the site via the content database like that and not `using (SPSite oSiteCollection = new SPSite("Absolute_URL")`?

Comment: I actually had the SPSite() way first. But that caused the same behavior, so I switched it to use the method shown above, which seems to be the way when using timer jobs.